# Service stack design decision

Tags: servicestack

I need some suggestions in the usage of Service stack. On the server we will have DTOs and services defined for it. But how can client knows about the DTOs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways you can document your API, and even provide generated code for your clients. Read the documentation for:

- [Generating typesafe client code](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Clients-overview)
- [Displaying a metadata page](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Metadata-page)
- [Integrating Swagger UI](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Swagger-API)

Comment: Not convinced with the approach of sharing DTO library with each client. Service stack forces the DTOs decoreate some attributes and extend some classes which is against to what they publicize " POCO-driven way of creating web services."